# Sqlite3 select query returning empty list\none value

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite, select

I am writing a python script that takes values stored in a local SQLite database.

When I execute a `SELECT` statement, it returns an empty list - when using `fetchall()` func & it returns a none value when using `fetchone()`. Similar situation occurs when using `fetchmany()`.

But when I use

```
SELECT * 
FROM DB 
WHERE FILENAME=###
```

it returns the complete values as normal.

[this is the first problem]

[this happens when I run this command]

[image: sqlite3]

Code:

```
 con = sqlite3.connect("userdatabase.db")
 c = con.cursor()
 c.execute('''SELECT DATA FROM main.USERDATAS WHERE FILENAME = "HAI" & FILEEXT="txt"''')
 d = c.fetchone()
 print(type(d))
 print(d)
```

output:

```
 <class 'NoneType'>
 None
```

When I use fetchall()

```
 import sqlite3
 con = sqlite3.connect("userdatabase.db")
 c = con.cursor()
 c.execute('''SELECT DATA FROM main.USERDATAS WHERE FILENAME = "HAI" & FILEEXT="txt     "''')
```

output

```
 <class 'list'>
 []
```

When I use `SELECT * FROM USERDATAS` it works fine

```
 import sqlite3
 con = sqlite3.connect("userdatabase.db")
 c = con.cursor()
 c.execute('''SELECT * FROM USERDATAS''')
 d = c.fetchall()
 print(type(d))
 print(d)
```

Output:

```
 <class 'list'>
 [('hai', 'txt', 'n dfndjkfbhjzvdfzdhnflkjh;k')]
```

Answer (score 0):

String constants in SQL are denoted by single quotes, not double-quotes. In addition, the logical "and" operator is `and`, not `&`:

```
c.execute('''SELECT DATA FROM main.USERDATAS WHERE FILENAME = \'HAI\' AND FILEEXT=\'txt\'''')
```

Comment: no..still it gives the same output.Is it because i try to access the database from another test file rather than the one i used to store the data.